# How @Resources annotation works

Tags: java, annotations, resources

I am studying @Resource, @Resources injection in java. Oracle docs and some other sites are explaining field, method and class resource injection with @Resource annotation but I could not find help for Multiple class resources injection using @Resources annotation - Actually I want to know how multiple resources declared by @Resources annotation on class will be used in class?
Example I am seeing on oracle docs on other sites is below:

```
@Resources({
    @Resource(name="myMessageQueue",
                    type="javax.jms.ConnectionFactory"),
    @Resource(name="myMailSession",
                    type="javax.mail.Session")
})
public class SomeMessageBean {
...
}
```

But how i will use myMessageQueue and myMailSession in class body? So anyone can explain class body implementation or sample method implementation showing the usage of above declared resources by @Resources annotation?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, `@Resources` is just an array of resource and inject the resource inside that array to your class during runtime.

```
package javax.annotation;
import java.lang.annotation.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.*;
import static java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.*;

/**
 * This class is used to allow multiple resources declarations.
 *
 * @see javax.annotation.Resource
 * @since 1.6, Common Annotations 1.0
 */

@Documented
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
public @interface Resources {
   /**
    * Array used for multiple resource declarations.
    */
   Resource[] value();
}
```

---

**EDIT**
The following code is from the implement from [org.apache.cxf.common.injection.ResourceInjector](http://www.javadocexamples.com/java_source/org/apache/cxf/common/injection/ResourceInjector.java.html)

```
  79:    // Implementation of org.apache.cxf.common.annotation.AnnotationVisitor
  80:
  81:    public final void visitClass(final Class<?> clz, final Annotation annotation) {
  82:        
  83:        assert annotation instanceof Resource || annotation instanceof Resources : annotation; 
  84:
  85:        if (annotation instanceof Resource) { 
  86:            injectResourceClassLevel(clz, (Resource)annotation); 
  87:        } else if (annotation instanceof Resources) { 
  88:            Resources resources = (Resources)annotation;
  89:            for (Resource resource : resources.value()) {
  90:                injectResourceClassLevel(clz, resource); 
  91:            }
  92:        } 
  93:
  94:    }
```

You can see in line89, it loops through the Resources array and inject the Resources.
Btw, you can get the Resources array by `Resource[] resoruces = CLASS_NAME.class.getAnnotation(Resources.class).value();`

Comment: "inject the resource inside that array to your class" - can you explain how to use these resources now after injection? any code implementation example please.

Comment: I seldom use ``@resources``. But when I check the implementation of ``ResourceInjector `` in ``org.apache.cxf.common.injection``. it actually loop through the resources array and create the resource one by one. I'll edit my answer above for your reference.